# Red/green border on object

Tags: light

When I turn the view into "render preview", I get this weird red/green border

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Even after opening a new project and loading factory settings I can't get rid of it.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you manage to make this happen on a different machine? Do you use default material? Do you render with Cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: I don't have any other machine to test it on. Yes everything is default I guess since I only moved the light and changed the mode to render preview. I render with EEVEE

Comment: Is your graphics card compatible with blender?

Comment: No I know it is not I render on CPU